# Is it a good idea to use Hashing (ORA_HASH) to define uniqueness in relational tables?

Tags: oracle, hash, etl

I have an XML file containing Client id and addresses which I need to load into relational tables in Oracle database.

```
<Clients>
<Client id="100">
    <name>ABC Corportation</name>
    <Address>
        <Addr1>1 Pine Street</Addr1>
        <City>Chennai</City>
        <State>Tamil Nadu</State>
        <Country>India</Country>
        <Postalcode>6000000</Postalcode>
    </Address>
    <Address>
        <Addr1>1 Apple Street</Addr1>
        <City>Coimbatore</City>
        <State>Tamil Nadu</State>
        <Country>India</Country>
        <Postalcode>6000101</Postalcode>
    </Address>
</Client>
<Client id="101">
....
....
</Client>
```

I have 2 relational tables defined as below-

### Client

CLIENT_ID (Unique Key)
CLIENT_NAME

### Client_Location

CLIENT_ID
ADDR1
CITY
STATE
COUNTRY
POSTAL_CODE

Updates to client address at source will sent in the XML file everyday. The ETL designed in a way that it requires a unique key on the table based on which it will identify the change coming in the XML as INSERT or UPDATE and accordingly sync the table to the XML. Identifying DELETEs is not really necessary.

Question: What should be defined as the unique key for Client_Location to process incremental changes coming everyday in the XML file? There is no identifier for address in the XML file. I was thinking about creating an additional hashing column (using ORA_HASH function) based on the 3 columns (STATE, COUNTRY, POSTAL_CODE). The unique key for the table would (CLIENT_ID, <>) which the ETL will use.. The idea is that it is not common for STATE/COUNTRY/POSTAL_CODE to change in an address. Ofcourse, this is a big assumption which I'm making. I would like to implement the below-

1) If there is any small change to ADDR1, I want the ETL to pick it up as a "valid" update at source and sync it to the table.
2) If there is a small change in the STATE/COUNTRY/POSTAL_CODE (eg: typo correction or case change like India to INDIA), then I don't want this to picked as a change because it would lead to INSERT (hashing value would change which is part of the unique key) and in turn duplicate rows in the table.

Does the idea of using a hashing column to define uniqueness make sense? Is there a better way to deal with this?
Is there a way to tweak ORA_HASH to produce results expected in #2 above?

Answer (score 1):

If the client can have only one location reuse `CLIENT_ID` as primary key.

If there are more locations posible add `SEQUENCE`key (sequence number 1..N) to the `CLIENT_ID` as a PK.

The simplest possibility to distinct and identify the locations is to use the feature of XML that the order of elements is well defined and has meaning. So the first ADDRESS element (pine street) becomes sequence 1, the second 2 and so on.

Please check the [FOR ORDINALITY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.) clause on XML table how to get this identification while parsing the XML.

You may also add `TIMESTAMP` (as a simple attribute - not a key) to keep the timestamp of the change and a `STATUS` column to identify deleted locations.

`HASH` may be usefull to quickly test a change if you have tons of columns, but for 5 columns it is probably an overkill (as you may simple compare the column values). I'd not recommend to used HASH as part of a key as it has no advantage to the proposed solution.

Comment: Thanks Marmite. A client can have more than one address.  The issue with version id is that it is only in target (Oracle table) and is not available at source (XML file). If a client has more than one address and one of the address is updated in the XML, then I cannot track it to the correct address row in the table.